# Can not replicate package using package manager

Tags: aem, sling, jackrabbit

I've been encountered an error when I replicate package to publish instance using CQ package manager. I'm using AEM 6.0 with service pack 2.

**The error displayed in 'activity log' panel**:

> Replicating package Error during processing:
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value for key checksum can't be
>   put into node: 1  at
>   org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.JcrModifiableValueMap.put(JcrModifiableValueMap.java:658)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.JcrModifiableValueMap.put(JcrModifiableValueMap.java:58)
>     at
>   com.adobe.acs.samples.replication.impl.SampleReplicationPreprocessor.preprocess(SampleReplicationPreprocessor.java:83)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReplicatorImpl.replicate(ReplicatorImpl.java:363)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReplicatorImpl.replicate(ReplicatorImpl.java:244)
>     at
>   com.day.crx.packaging.impl.J2EEPackageManager.replicatePackage(J2EEPackageManager.java:601)
>     at
>   com.day.crx.packaging.impl.J2EEPackageManager.doPost(J2EEPackageManager.java:195)
>     at
>   com.day.crx.packaging.impl.PackageManagerServlet.doPost(PackageManagerServlet.java:144)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:339)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: No matching property
>   definition: checksum = 1  at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.NodeDelegate.setProperty(NodeDelegate.java:522)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl$35.perform(NodeImpl.java:1308)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl$35.perform(NodeImpl.java:1297)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.perform(SessionDelegate.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.ItemImpl.perform(ItemImpl.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl.internalSetProperty(NodeImpl.java:1297)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl.setProperty(NodeImpl.java:340)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.JcrModifiableValueMap.put(JcrModifiableValueMap.java:654)
>     ... 75 more
>
> Error: Value for key checksum can't be put into node: 1

[image]

Any solutions are appreciate. thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the acs-aem-samples package from your instance and you should be fine.

Comment: it's works. many thanks :)